# Spring REST controller method parameter annotated with @RequestHeader returns wrong value

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have implemented a Request filter (extends OncePerRequestFilter)
and I return a HttpServletRequestWrapper where I have overridden the
ACCEPT header.

When the controller method is invoked:

```
@ResponseBody
public Foo getFoo(HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestHeader(value=ACCEPT) String injectedAcceptHeader,
    @PathVariable ("fooId") String fooId) {
    log.info("injected accept header: {}", injectedAcceptHeader);
    log.info("accept header value from request: {}",
        request.getHeader(ACCEPT));
    ...
```

The injectedAcceptHeader is not the same as the one from the Request.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you post the logged output?

Comment: The ACCEPT header from the request - which is the wrapper request created in the filter - is correct: ACCEPT application/json
The injectedAcceptHeader is the original value from the unwrapped request: ACCEPT application/vnd+special.json